# How do I interpret an AudioBuffer and get the power?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

I am trying to make a volume-meter for my app, which will show while recording a video. I have found a lot of support for such meters for iOS, but mostly for `AVAudioPlayer`, which is no option for me. I am using `AVCaptureSession` to record, and will then end up with the delegate method shown below:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);

    CFRetain(sampleBuffer);
    CFRetain(formatDescription);

    if(connection == audioConnection)
    {
        CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
        AudioBufferList audioBufferList;

        CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, 
            NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(AudioBufferList), NULL, NULL,
            kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment,
            &blockBuffer);

        SInt16 *data = audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mData;
    }
    //Releases etc..
}
```

(Only showing relevant code)

Of what I understand, I receive a 'sample buffer', containing either audio or video. Once I've verified that the connection indeed is audio, then I 'extract' the audioBufferList from the buffer, and I am sitting here left with a list of one (or more?) audioBuffers. The actual data is, as I understand, represented as `SInt16`, or '16 bits signed integer', which as far as I understand has a range from `-32,768` to `32,767`. However, if I simply print out this received value, I get A LOT of bouncing numbers. When in "silence" I get values bouncing rapidly between `-200` and `200`, and when there's noise I get values from `-4,000` to `13,000`, completely out of order.
As I've understood from reading, the value `0` will represent silence. However, I do not understand the difference between negative and positive values, as well as I do not know if the are able to reach all the way up/down to `+-32,768`.

I believe I need a percentage of how 'loud' it is, but have been unable to find anything.

I have read a couple of tutorials and references on the matter, but nothing makes sense to me. I followed one guide by doing this(appending to the code above, inside the `if`):

```
float accumulator = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize; i++)
    accumulator += data[i] * data[i];
float power = accumulator / audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize;
float decibels = log10f(power);
NSLog(@"%f", decibels);
```

Apparently, this code was supposed to align from `-1` to `+1`, but that did not happen. I am now getting values around `6.194681` when silence, and `7.773492` for some noise. This is feels like the correct 'range', but in the 'wrong place'. I can't simply subtract 7 from the number and assume I'm between `-1` and `+1`. There should be some logic and science behind how this should work, but I do not know enough about how digital audio works.

Does anyone know the logic behind this? Is 0 always silence while `-32,768` and `32,767` are loud noises? Can I then simply multiply all negative values by `-1` to always get positive values, and then find out how many percent they are at (between 0 and 32767)? Somehow, I don't believe this will work, as I guess there is a reason for the negative values.. I'm not completely sure what to try.

Comment: I recommend reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation for background

Comment: @sbooth Thanks, I learned from that, but sadly nothing to solve my issue. I'm not completely understanding how the data I have can represent 'loudness'. The 'power'. When I speak into the microphone now, a bunch of numbers prints out in my log. They vary when I raise my voice. Do they only represent how loud I'm talking, or do they also represent the rest, as in what I'm saying/my frequency etc.? How then can I find the min/max for the volume..

Comment: The numbers represent the entire signal- your voice's volume, frequency, etc.  There are different ways to calculate the loudness- the simplest is probably to choose a sample window (1/10th of a second for example) and then calculate the RMS power. This won't be a really good estimate of loudness but it will be a start.

Comment: You are missing a square root in this line - float power = accumulator / audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize;

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @SJ3040 I think I ended up with just subtracting 6 or 7 as I wrote.. Never found a good solution. But I scrapped the whole project, so can't check. It worked 'fine'..

Comment: you read buffer as SInt*, so the bufferCount must be half of audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize. Have you try audioBufferList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize/2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your question is wrong in several ways. This code is trying to copy that from the article below, but you've not handled it properly converting from the float-based code in the article to 16-bit integer math. You're also looping on the wrong number of values (max i) and will end up pulling in garbage data. So this is all kinds of wrong.

https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-10-12-obtaining-and-interpreting-audio-data.html

The code in the article is correct. Here's what it is, expanded a bit. This is only looking at the first buffer in a 32-bit float buffer list.

```
float accumulator = 0;
AudioBuffer buffer = bufferList->mBuffers[0];
float * data = (float *)buffer.mData;
UInt32 numSamples = buffer.mDataByteSize / sizeof(float);

for (UInt32 i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
    accumulator += data[i] * data[i];
}
float power = accumulator / (float)numSamples;
float decibels = 10 * log10f(power);
```

As the article says, the result here is decibels uses 0dB reference. eg, 0.0 is the *maximum* value. This is the same thing that AVAudioPlayer's averagePowerForChannel returns for example.

To use this in your 16-bit integer context, you'd need to a) loop appropriately through each 16-bit sample, b) convert the data[i] value from a 16-bit integer to a floating point value in the [-1.0, 1.0] range before squaring and adding to the accumulator.

Comment: Thank you. The question was posted six years ago, so I am in no position to try it out, but I appreciate the detailed response and assume you are correct.